# Css Displaying only center part of image

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to display only center part of of image. For eg an image height =300 px and width=520px using CSS or JQUERY css would be better if possible else i can use Jquery, Googling didnt helped me

is it possible that i can show only 200 * 130 form the center using css
for eg

```
 -----------------------
|                       |
|       --------        |
|      |Need this|      |
|      | Part    |      |
|       ---------       |
|_______________________|
```

Comment: Can the image be a background to a div or is it given in the HTML that it's an `<img>` tag?

Comment: can it be an img tag? it would be good to learn using img tag

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can set the image as the bg of an element, and then something like this:

```css
        div {
            background: #eee url(http://www.google.co.cr/logos/classicplus.png) center center;
            width: 100px;
            height:100px;
            border: 1px solid red;
            text-indent: -9999px;
        }
```

```html
<img src="http://www.google.co.cr/logos/classicplus.png">
<div>some text that won't be seen</div>
```

And end up with something like http://jsfiddle.net/9nBRe/

Comment: thumbs up. cant vote up new to stackoverflow thanks for help.....consider voting for my question

Comment: i need the img tag is it possible using img tag ? as the area needs to be clickable
or a way to make div clickable?

Comment: if you want users to be able to CLICK on the image, then you should the background image to your <a> tag, instead of your <img> tag, so you would have something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vgNjd/

Answer (score 1):

set following CSS :

> .background{
>
> background-position: -200px -130px;
>   background-image:url("image_name.png");
>       width:200px;  height:130px;
>
> }

Comment: i need the img tag... is it possible using img tag ? as the area needs to be clickable
or a way to make div clickable?

Comment: Its not possible using image tag...one solution for this is just add one <div> and assign above css to this div and add click event to this div...

Answer (score 1):

If the image needs to be an `<img>` element, you can do it using an overlay image with a transparent "hole" punched in the center.

See http://jsfiddle.net/jkwSe/1/.

It's hard to see, but the image on top is white, but has a transparent center, like a rectangular donut. I left a little of the image on the right so you can see the effect.

Comment: What's the desired effect? Do you want the overlay to blend in with the background of the page?

Comment: Need the center part of the img cut, as in jsfiddle there is white area around, i need the img tag as i need to hyperlink the centered image thumbnail
for eg i need to show a big banner image and underneath the small thumbnail and clicking on thumbnail takes user to payment process
So that we get crux(important) part in thumbnail
, I am trying t get image(thumbnail) form the center

Comment: In that case, I don't think my solution is the right one. The other answers are probably better - or if you'd like to use the `img` tag, you can use jQuery's crop plugin (http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-
Here we need to apply image as background. I mean, we can't put `<img />` tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Image Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="height:300px;width:520px;text-align:center;">
<div style="width:200px;height:130px;background:Transparent url('http://www.bing.com/fd/hpk2/Nautilus_ROW880768633.jpg') center center;margin:85px auto;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible using CSS `clip` propery. For more information see [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip)

As for example in question asked, code would go:

```
img {
  position: absolute;
  rect: (50px, 195px, 50px, 195px);

}
```

Clip needs `position: absolute` to work so it's probably good idea to put wrap `<img>` in `<div>` (or `<figure>` or wathever) and set it to `position: relative` to contain image in document flow

Comment: Just last (on Apr 14'17) info: clip is deprecated, [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) is recommended (but browser support is not great now)

Answer (score 0):

This worked better for me.

In style.css or  tag.

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    object-fit: fill;
}
```

Or straight in the HTML.

```
<img style="width: 100%; height: 100px; object-fit: fill;" src="file.jpg" alt="">
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.